# how to extract variable from JSON response array on condition basis in postman?

Tags: arrays, json, postman

```js
[
    {
        "Value": "987654",
        "Type": "EF"
    },
    {
        "Value": "987159",
        "Type": "DE"
    },
    {
        "Value": "987789",
        "Type": "CD"
    },
    {
        "Value": "987456",
        "Type": "BC"
    },
    {
        "Value": "987123",
        "Type": "AB"
    }
]
```

I WANT to fetch Value on the basis of Type, and save it to Environment variable, if Type= CD, Value set to environment variable CDValue=987789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

In tab `Test` in Postman:

```
const res = pm.response.json();
res.forEach((e) => {
    pm.environment.set(e.Type + "Value", e.Value);
})
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @lucasnguyen17, it's working...

Comment: @GavendraSingh Please accept it as a correct answer and upvote